# Elegant method of arranging several aligned plots with specified empty elements

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation

I want to display a series of plots that are aligned, but with certain array positions being empty.

If I generate an array of plots like this:

```
multiplots = 
Partition[
Table[ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True], 12], 
          3];
GraphicsGrid @multiplots
```

[image: plotgrid1]

I can use `ReplacePart` to swap out certain plots with an 'invisible' object, e.g.

```
blank = Graphics[{Directive[White], Rectangle[]}];
 GraphicsGrid@
  ReplacePart[multiplots, {{2, 2} -> blank, {3, 3} -> blank}]
```

[image: plotgrid2]

The result is fine but the method seems clunky. Is there a more elegant way to generate graphics arrays with empty elements?

Comment: You can also use `Null` instead of `blank`.

Comment: @Henrik I think that definitely qualifies as more elegant :)

Comment: The scientific publishing package [SciDraw](https://scidraw.nd.edu) has replaced the earlier version of LevelScheme.  SciDraw makes lots of these kinds of presentation thing much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would use LevelScheme for this.

```
Quiet@Needs["LevelScheme`LevelScheme`"]

Figure[{
  SetOptions[SchemeObject, FontFamily -> "Helvetica LT Std", 
   FontSize -> 08],
  Multipanel[{4, 3},
   Margin -> 50,
   XPlotRanges -> {0, 25},
   YPlotRanges -> {0, 100},
   XFrameLabels -> None, BufferB -> 5,
   YFrameLabels -> None, BufferL -> 7,
   XFrameTicks -> Automatic,
   YFrameTicks -> Automatic,
   YGapSizes -> .05, XGapSizes -> .05,
   YPanelSizes -> 1,
   XPanelSizes -> 1,
   First -> "A",
   Order -> Horizontal
   ],
  FigurePanel[{1, 1}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True],
  FigurePanel[{1, 2}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True],
  FigurePanel[{1, 3}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True],
  FigurePanel[{2, 1}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True],
  (*FigurePanel[{2, 2}],*)
  FigurePanel[{2, 3}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True],
  FigurePanel[{3, 1}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True],
  FigurePanel[{3, 2}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True],
  (*FigurePanel[{3, 3}],*)
  FigurePanel[{4, 1}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True],
  FigurePanel[{4, 2}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True],
  FigurePanel[{4, 3}],
  RawGraphics@ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Frame -> True]
  },
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

An extensive manual & examples allows lots of fine tuning of the resulting plot
[image]